# Как взять из одной таблицы данные и записать в другую (RedbeanPHP)

Tags: redbeanphp

Заранее спасибо за ответ. Есть задача взять записи с одной таблицы,а затем записать в другую и потом вайпнуть из которой брали данные.
Перепробовано было всё... 
tour - таблица турниров
tourplay - связанная одик к одному (турнир с игроками) таблица
users - таблица пользователей
player - таблица с участниками, которая после формирования турнира сотрется до следующего турнира.
Фрагмент кода выполнения действия:

```
require('libs/db.php');
$users = R::findAll('users');
$player = R::findAll('players');

   if (isset($_POST['begintour'])) {
  unset($_POST['begintour']);
  $tour = R::dispense('tournament');
  $tour->name = $_POST['tour'];
  $tour->status = 'started';
  $tour->date = R::isoDateTime();
  $tourplay = R::dispense('participants');

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $load = R::load('players', $key);
    $tourplay->nickname = $load->nickname;
    $tour->ownProductList[] = $tourplay;
    $tourplay->round = R::load('rounds',1);
    $load = R::store($tour);
  }
  // R::wipe('players');
}



<form action="" method="post">
    <input type='text' placeholder='Название турнира' name='tour'>
<?php foreach ($player as $players) { 
echo "<input style='display: none;' type='checkbox' name='".$players->id."' CHECKED value='on'>"; } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="begintour">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказывается было гораздо проще чем я думал))))
добавил отвязку после нажатия `unset($_POST['tour']);` и всё заработало ;). Сам задал вопрос и сам же на него ответил!